# Write spark dataframe to fixed width file java spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have read a CSV into dataframe using java spark dataframe, now I have to apply some width to each colum and write that data into a fixed width file. For example..column 1 has 2 bit width, column 2 has 7 bit...like that I have 85 columns. Can someone explain me how can I wrote data in dataframe to a fixed width file using java spark. I need solution in java spark only

Comment: Map each row of the dataframe to a single string with the spacing you need

Answer (score 0):

Without more description (and code example), I'd propose something like:

```
public Dataset<String> toFixedWidthString(Dataset<MyClass> inputDataset, int width) {
    return inputDataset.map(myClass ->
        String.format("%" + width + "s", myClass.toString()), Encoders.STRING());
}
```

Comment: Each column has separate width....I think your code is for converting entire dataframe to a string dataset with the specified width...but my each column has different width..I need to apply different width to each column...in that case this code will not work

Comment: Well, I would need more of your code (the data model at least) to give a more detailed answer. What you can do is to simply improve the String.format I wrote to write what ever you want such as `String.format("%s, %s, %s", myClass.fieldA, myClass.fieldB, myClass.filedC)`