# How to use Spark Dataframe/Dataset/RDD to Write Output data in text file/parquet format using fixed length assigned to each output attribute

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was trying to read a csv file in spark dataframe/dataset and was writing  the content of csv file using fixed length format in the output. But couldn't find a proper way to do that in spark builtin functions.Assume the csv file has the following data
Header : Name address Age
Data   : A    aa      1
BB   bbb     2
CCC  cccc    3

Assume that while writing the above csv data to an output location The column name "Name" has to be written with 5 character always, Address column with 10 characters and Age column with 3 characters.
So while writing the output, respective columns will always have a width of 5,10 & 3 characters.
If the value within each column does not consume the full width of that column, the remaining characters
of that column should fill it with white space or some configurable special character.
So the output should look like below. In the below output I am filling the remaining characters of each output column with white spaces. For better readability I am wrapping the output  value within double quotes so that it is easier for the reviewers to count the remaining number of characters filled
with white spaces. Or each attribute within output field can also be delimited with a pipe character enforcing the fixed length constraint to each field.
Header : Name      address       Age
Data   : "A    "   "aa        "  "9  "
"BB   "   "bbb       "  "50 "
"CCC  "   "cccc      "  "100"

```
I was trying to integrate the BeanIO mapping(http://beanio.org/) to Spark if that is feasible to do so and enforce the fixed length constraint to each column, but no luck so far.
```

I was able to do that in pure java code with the help of bean io libraries, but was checking if the same can be done in spark by integrating with  beanio  and enforce fixed length constraint to each output column, and see if we can get performance benefit if the input dataset is very huge.
Or is there  any alternative way to do that in spark using dataset,dataframe or rdd by attaching some
custom scema to it or by broadcasting a bean io xml mapping file(as per bean io documentation) to executor nodes and iterate the partitions within executor and write the contents of each partition to an output text file with fixed length characters assigned to each field. I tried to do so in spark with some sample code snippets , but got stuck up with not seeing proper built in spark functions to do so.
Trying to do that in Spark Java instead of Spark scala or python.

Tried to do that with a Spark sample but couldn't complete because of not seeing proper inbuild functions to do so in spark. Found some similar link, but couldn't find any proper code samples to do so.
[Write spark dataframe to fixed width file java spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64914929/write-spark-dataframe-to-fixed-width-file-java-spark)

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do this. With pure SQL, just cast each column as char(desired width).  Pyspark, you can use `format_string`, `rpad` with scala...